# Adding existing lookup records to the custom object (simple VF page)

Tags: visualforce

I have a very simple VF page that gets called through a custom button “Add Instructor” on a custom object “Course”. On that page, I only have one lookup field “Instructor” that looks for existing instructors. 
I would like to add the instructor from that lookup field to the custom object “Course”.

When I find my instructor through lookup, I click on a “Save” button on my VF page but nothing happens and the instructor doesn’t get added to the course.
I am very new to the VF and Apex and I am using a standard controller for this custom object (no extensions, no custom controllers) and I think this is probably why nothing happens.

Could you please tell me what exactly I should do for “Save” button to actually save and add the record found through the lookup field on the custom object “Course”?

Do I need extension from a standard to a custom controller or do I need a custom controller and how do I create one?

My Simple VF page code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Courses__c" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Add Existing Instructor">

            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:inputField value="{! Courses__c.Instructor__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>    

            <apex:pageBlockButtons > 
                <apex:commandButton action="{! save }" value="Save"/>       
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: This is correct. I just tried it. It saved my record. You don't need an extension. What is it, a detail page button?

Comment: You could have a validation rule or something preventing you from updating the record. Add an `<apex:[messages|message|pagemessages]>` to your page so any error messages can be displayed

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have mentioned that my custom button calling the VF page is located on the Related List. the button works and it calls the VF page and i get to choose the instructor from the lookup but when i click on Save it does not save that lookup record on the related list "instructors".

Comment: I did not create any validation rules for this custom app.

Comment: Eric, where exactly in the page should i add the line you suggested? I tried on several places but i get this error: Error: CreateInstructor line 2, column 7: Element type "apex:" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>" 
Error Error: Element type "apex:" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

Comment: N.B - it is a list Button calling VF page through javascript (window.location = 'apex/CreateInstructor') because i could not have the detailed button on the related list. I could only have the list button.

Comment: @Adriana - Its not literally `[messages|message.....` the items in the `[]` are the options, pick one i.e. `<apex:messages/>`. and put it anywhere that it renders when the page loads. Even though you marked as solved, good Idea to get in the habit of putting in a messages element. helpful in situations like these or to show messages to users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have course and Instructor two different object.
Is that master detail relationship or Lookup ?

If you want to change the instructor edit the pageLayout and add the instructor field. So you can change with out writing code.

If its master detail ensure you have correct layout added in the course layout.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and you are correct. I have two custom objects: Instructor and Course and i have a lookup relationship created on both. Let's say i create a new course, I then want to go to that course record and add the existing instructor to it. So when i go to the course record, i would like to see the instructors associated with that specific course. what is the best practice for this? Thanks again

Comment: Also, i can have multiple instructors teaching one course so i would like all instructor records for that course showing up in the related list.

Comment: Is that course and instructor relationship is one to many.  [For One course many instructor ] ?  Then create master detail relation field in instructor.